# How to add Preview Screen to SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, preview, savefiledialog, print-preview

I am trying to add a preview screen as you would have one in the PrintPreviewDialog into SaveFileDialog. I also am confused if I can customize how the output of the text is on the document and the style it's displayed in. Sorry English isn't my primary language so I will add some pictures to explain what I am talking about. I am using C# to accomplish my goal. My question is how can I preview screen as you would have one in the PrintPreviewDialog into SaveFileDialog? Thank you again! [The code of the printPreviewDialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zq7up.png)

```
namespace AAI_Interview_Application.Forms
```

{
       public partial class internForm : Form
    {
        public internForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void internForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        internForm interForm = new internForm();

        FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;

        interForm.AutoScroll = true;
        interForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }

    private void label13_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, 
    LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://google.com");
        }
        catch { }

    }
}
```

}

[How I want my preview looking like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYahG.png)

Comment: We don't like pictures of code.  You haven't asked a question or explained what is wrong.

Comment: add some codes to explain your problem

Comment: Are you trying to print your invoice as images?

Comment: No, I am trying to get a preview screen for savefiledialog @TideGu